# Convert Scala ArrayBuffer to Iterator

Tags: scala, collections

I have a Scala method that accepts inputs, creates an `ArrayBuffer[Widget]` based on those inputs, but then must convert that array buffer into an `Iterator[Widget]`:

```
def createWidgetIterator(isFizz : Boolean, buzz : String) : Iterator[Widget] = {
    val widgetBuffer = new ArrayBuffer[Widget]()

    // ...Use some logic to add Widget instances to widgetBuffer
    // widgetBuffer += new Widget(...)     etc.

    // At this point widgetBuffer is full of Widget instances

    // TODO: Convert widgetBuffer to Iterator[Widget]
    val widgetIterator : Iterator[Widget] = null // ???

    widgetIterator
}
```

Anybody know how I can do this type of conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `toIterator` on array buffer to get an iterator

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val ab = ArrayBuffer(1, 2)
ab: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2)

scala> ab.toIterator
res1: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator
```

For your code

```
def createWidgetIterator(isFizz : Boolean, buzz : String) : Iterator[Widget] = {
    val widgetBuffer = new ArrayBuffer[Widget]()
    widgetBuffer.toIterator
}
```